# Как управлять движущимся элементом?(css)

Tags: html, css

Нужно что бы Машина ехала от левой части экрана к правой, поворачивалась и ехала назад, и так продолжается бесконечно.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.road {
  height: 252px;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
}

.road .block_track {
  width: 390px;
  height: 100%;
  animation-name: shake;
  animation-duration: 6s;
  animation-timing-function: ease-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: normal;
}

.road .block_track .track {
  height: 100%;
  width: 389px;
  background: url(../images/fireTrack.png);
  animation-name: twist;
  animation-duration: 0.3s;
  animation-iteration-count: 5;
  animation-direction: normal;
  animation-delay: 3s;
}

.road .track .lineWheel {
  width: 295px;
  height: 79px;
  position: fixed;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-left: 62px;
  margin-top: 201px;
}

.road .track .light {
  position: fixed;
  width: 25px;
  height: 31px;
  background: url(../images/blue.png) no-repeat;
  background-color: blue;
  box-shadow: 2px -13px 20px -2px blue;
  margin-top: 39px;
  margin-left: 240px;
}

.road .track .lineWheel .wheel {
  width: 75px;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(../images/col.png) no-repeat;
}

@keyframes shake {
  50% {
    transform: translate(976px, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes twist {
  100% {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Fire Track</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="road">
    <div class="block_track">
      <div class="track">
        <div class="light"></div>
        <div class="lineWheel">
          <div class="wheel front"></div>
          <div class="wheel back"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

Так?
Если что-то не понятно, пишите, отвечу.

```css
.road {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
  position: relative;
}

.car {
  display: block;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Illustration_of_on_off-road_automobile.png') no-repeat center center / 100%;
  animation: drive 5s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

@keyframes drive {
  0% {  
    left: 0%;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  
  49.9% {  
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  
  50% {  
    left: calc(100% - 230px);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  
  100% {  
    left: 0%;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="road">
  <div class="car"></div>
</div>
```

---

Вариант с колёсами

```css
.road {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #333;
  position: relative;
}

.car {
  display: block;
  width: 230px;
  height: 100px;
  background: url('https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/0/01/Illustration_of_on_off-road_automobile.png') no-repeat center center / 100%;
  animation: drive 5s linear infinite;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0%;
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.wheel {
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: url('https://purepng.com/public/uploads/large/purepng.com-car-wheelcar-wheelcarwheeltire-1701527840935bi4mr.png') no-repeat center center / 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  animation: wheel 1.2s linear infinite;
}

.wheel:first-child {
  left: 38.25px;
}

.wheel:last-child {
  right: 11.5px;
}

@keyframes drive {
  0% {  
    left: 0%;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  
  49.9% {  
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  
  50% {  
    left: calc(100% - 230px);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  
  100% {  
    left: 0%;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
}

@keyframes wheel {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="road">
  <div class="car">
    <div class="wheel"></div>
    <div class="wheel"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```